# Action approved - publish_actions still not working

Tags: action, publish, facebook-opengraph

This question has been asked many times before, but they all seem to relate to problems before the Open Graph was 'opened'. As a new user, I also can't make this question useful, i.e no images or links. If you want to see the images I've posted, you'll have to copy and paste.

First of all, **my Action is approved**.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAFHr.png

Additionally, the action shows as being available to all users.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrrWW.png

`publish_actions` has been added to the Auth.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdJiA.png

I also have objects and aggregations setup correctly.

The auth preview also shows the correct settings (although the dialog currently doesn't stay open to see it, it used to).

When I try and connect with FB to the site, I don't see `publish_actions`. Instead I see the second stage of the dialog, for `publish_stream`. I set this by mistake the first time I saved the app, but quickly changed it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n819f.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkXfg.png

This is where I think it gets even stranger. If I take a look at the FB profile for one of the app developers, and click through too the app from there, while not registered, I see the correct permissions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsOVI.png

Yet another twist to the tale, which makes it even harder for me to debug, is that it seems since playing with the aggregations, I can't even get publish_actions permissions despite being listed as an app admin. (I've read that every action needs an aggregation before FB will process any actions sent by the server.)

```
/**/ FB.ApiServer._callbacks.ff2f1615c({"error":{"message":"(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions or App must be on whitelist","type":"OAuthException","code":200}});
```

That's the error I get when I complete the action on the site, http://purple.fr/boutique

Have I missed a setting somewhere? Have I done something I shouldn't? Should any of this be controlled in the code on the site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user connects to your site, you should be asking for the publish_actions permission instead of the publish_stream permission. The referral dialog settings (where you already ask for publish_actions) only works when a user clicks on the action from within Facebook. It won't work for users already on your website.

In your login function (`FB.login`), make sure you add the permission `publish_actions`.

That aside, it looks like it's all working now.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAosv.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbgf5.png

Comment: This was the crucial bit I missed: "In your login function (FB.login), make sure you add the permission publish_actions." So simple!